# Locating the right tag in HTML while webscraping in python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping

Im working on a project for school were I display the current price for bitcoin, eth and maybe another and im web scraping https://cryptowat.ch/ but I cant find the tag used to store the live price. when i parse the div tag it returns the price but im not able to isolate it so i can display it in python

```
<div class="rankings-col__header__segment"><h2>BTC</h2><weak>usd </weak>10857.00</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand - you know the `BTC` string and can use it to base your locator.

So, if it would be XPath, you can use that and `following-sibling::text()`:

```
//h2[. = 'BTC']/following-sibling::text()
```

Example using `lxml.html`:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

data = """<div class="rankings-col__header__segment"><h2>BTC</h2><weak>usd </weak>10857.00</div>"""

root = fromstring(data)
print(root.xpath("//h2[. = 'BTC']/following-sibling::text()"))
```

Prints `['10857.00']`.

---

If, by any chance, you use `BeautifulSoup`, it would be:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """<div class="rankings-col__header__segment"><h2>BTC</h2><weak>usd </weak>10857.00</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
print(soup.find("h2", string="BTC").find_next_sibling(text=True))
```

Comment: @KushalS well, I was only trying to help with locating the element part. I suspect you have a bigger problem - actually getting the desired HTML with the desired elements downloaded.

Comment: hi alec, im able to pull the html line from above using the following, 
`containers = page_soup.findAll("span",{"class":"price-right"})

container = containers[0] #this returns the HTML 

print(container)`

 when i try to pass the container variable through 
`print(container.find("h2", string="BTC").find_next_sibling(text=True))`
 i get an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next_sibling'

Comment: @KushalS where is that `span` with `price-right` coming from. Try use `soup` instead of `container`. Thanks.